# Flutter - List of MilliSecondsSinceEpoch to List of DateTime

Tags: flutter, dart

I am still new to flutter and learning how to deal with lists. In this case, I have a list of `millisecondsSinceEpoch` so (`List<int>` in Firestore) and I want to generate a new `List<DateTime>` of dates from those integers. However, I am not sure how to handle that with the `DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch()`.

The error is `The argument type 'List<int>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.` I understand it is not looking for a list, but not sure how to pass that properly.

```
//updatesDateEpoch is a list of int
 List<int> datesSec = logRecord.updatesDateEpoch.asList();

//error caused when passing dateSec
 List<DateTime> datesList = [DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(datesSec)];
```

Comment: You have to iterate through datesSec and convert every element to DateTime, like this: `List<DateTime> datesList = datesSec.map((e) => DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(e)).toList();`

Comment: Thank you! As a follow-up question, how would you then map through the new `List<DateTime>` to reformat them using `DateFormat`? This doesn't appear to be working `List<String> formatedDates = datesList.map((a) => DateFormat('EEE, M/d/y').format(a));`

Comment: You just need to call `.toList()` at the end because `map` returns `Iterable`. So it should be like:  `List<String> formatedDates = datesList.map((a) => DateFormat('EEE, M/d/y').format(a)).toList();`

Comment: @AnteBule I just realized that :). Thank you very much, it seems to be working now!

Answer (score 1):

```
final datesList = datesSec.map(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch).toList();
```

Aside: some people are working too hard at this.  Whenever you have the form:

```
(a) => someFunction(a)
```

you should be getting a lint that says "unnecessary closure", because you can replace that with just:

```
someFunction
```

because the function name is indeed a function that takes a single value and returns a result!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the `DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch` function is expecting a **int** parameter and you are passing the whole **List**, to simplify your code and solve the error you can do this:

Code:

```
//updatesDateEpoch is a list of int
List<int> datesSec = logRecord.updatesDateEpoch.asList();

//The new list in milliseconds
List<DateTime> datesList = List.generate(datesSec.length, (index) => DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(datesSec[index]));
```

`List.generate` takes two parameters:

- The first is how long the list will be, in this case it's the size of your previous list, so we pass `datesSec.length` as the first parameter.
- The second parameter is the callback function that will receive the position of the element in this new list, we use this position to select a specific element in the previous list with `datesSec[index]` and then we pass the element in `DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(datesSec[index])`.

And so a new millisecond list is successfully created.